# Serve index.html from npm package to be able to split back end and front end into two different npm projects

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I want to split my server code and client code into two different npm packages. So instead of having something that looks like this:

```
exampleStructure.
|   package.json
|
\---src
    |   index.js
    |
    \---client
        |   index.js
        |
        \---public
                index.html
```

I want to have a structure that looks more like this:

```
exampleStructure.
+---client
|   |   package.json
|   |
|   +---build
|   |   |   index.js
|   |   |
|   |   \---public
|   |           index.html
|   |
|   \---src
|       +---app
|       |       index.js
|       |
|       \---www
|               index.html
|
\---server
    |   package.json
    |
    \---src
            index.js
```

In the `server` project I can have `client` as a dependency using `file:../client`, so I don't have to deploy it to npm, and then route it to `/*` as normal. This way I can separate the building process for the different projects, for example I can have a Typescript project on the back end that is being built with `tscomp` or `Gulp` and in the `client` project I can simply have `create-react-app`. Then if I want I could also have for example `Nodemon` watching the server but using `React Hot Loader` with webpack dev server for the front end. That way I can leverage all the best tools for each project and I don't have to be afraid of removing dependencies when refactoring (for example changing from React to Angular2/Vue/whatnot) and I can easily using different testing frameworks as well.

Now my question is, how do I actually create a package with static assets (like index.html) and serve it in a different package (using ie Node and Express)?

Answer (score 0):

i don't think its a good idea, but lets theoretically say that we agree.

so in my case we have some common modules in separate project and we use it by linking the project using npm link you can do something similar however everything will get complied in linked project. so you have to export everything , which can be achieved using the default webpack config with entry point to a file which will export all components and custom config for running child project in dev mode.

then in server build project, use routes from child project or create a saperate route file will exported components